# How do I insert variable values into HTML tags in ERB templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a partial like:

```
<% office.map do |o| %>
   <input id='city' name='company[company_office][0][city]' value=.... type='text' />
<% end %>
```

How can I insert a value like `o.office` into an attribute? `value="#{o.office}"` does not work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
<% office.map do |o| %>
   <input id='city' name='company[company_office][0][city]' value='<%= o.office %>' type='text' />
<% end %>
```

or you could use the form helpers for that

Comment: no, form helpers i can't use, because i have specific name. Big thanks, i don't know, that i want to write quotes )

Comment: what do you mean specific name? also, traversing to a loop and creating inputs with the same id is not recommended. you should make your id and name dynamic.

Answer (score 9):

Use embedded ruby(erb) tags,

```
<%= o.office %>
```

The only time you'd use `#{o.office}` is when you're not using **erb**. In a helper method for example and you want to use your ruby in a string. But when you're in an `html.erb` file, you have to use the erb tags.

Comment: <%= content_tag :input, :id => "city", :name => "company[company_office][0][city]", :value => "#{o.office}", :type => "text" %>

Could do it that way I suppose.

Comment: Agree with top voted answers. `<%= o.office %>` Just wanted to add that it's important for beginners to recognize distinction btwn erb tags with and without equals sign. `<%= ... %>` versus `<% ... %>` **Tag with an equals sign** indicates that enclosed code is an expression and renders code as a string. Used to embed line of code into template of to display contents of a variable. **Tags without the equals sign** commonly used for including loops / conditional logic in Ruby.